# MDCCardCollectionCell doesn't call didSelect method - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, material-components, iosdeployment

I am trying to custom `UICollectionViewCell` by using `material-components` called `MDCCardCollectionCell`. But when i implement it successfully which means when i click on each cell i can see animate and so on.. But one issue after implemented that class `MDCCardCollectionCell` then method `didSelect` is never call when i click on each and every cell.

Before it was working fine, after i implemented `MDCCardCollectionCell` then the issue occurs.
How to solve this particular issue?

Here is what i have done so far

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ExploreCellData

    cell.exploreData = exploreCategory?.data![indexPath.item]

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    cell.isSelectable = true
    cell.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.setShadowElevation(ShadowElevation(rawValue: 6), for: .selected)
    cell.setShadowColor(UIColor.black, for: .highlighted)
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let data = exploreCategory?.data![indexPath.item] {
        if let titleImage = data.imageName {
            print(titleImage)
            // This will push to another view controller after selected
            dashboardViewController?.showDetailEachItem(data: titleImage, imageContent: data.titleImage!, imageDesc: data.descImage!)
        }

    }

}
```

`ExploreCellData` is a custom cell using `MDCCardCollectionCell`

```
class ExploreCellData: MDCCardCollectionCell {

var exploreData: ExploreDataSection? {
    didSet{
        if let image = exploreData?.imageName {

            viewsProperty.exploreImageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
            viewsProperty.exploreNameLabel.text = exploreData?.titleImage
        }
    }
}

var viewsProperty = ExploreCategoryComponents()



let nameLabelView: UIView = {

    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    return view
}()



override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)


    setupConstraint()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



}
extension ExploreCellData {

func setupConstraint() {

    addSubview(viewsProperty.cardView)

    viewsProperty.cardView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

    viewsProperty.cardView.addSubview(viewsProperty.exploreImageView)
    viewsProperty.cardView.addSubview(nameLabelView)
    viewsProperty.cardView.addSubview(viewsProperty.exploreNameLabel)

    viewsProperty.exploreImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: frame.width - 10, height: frame.height / 1.5)

    //        nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width / 5, y: imageView.frame.maxY + 2, width: frame.width, height: frame.height / 4)

    viewsProperty.exploreNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewsProperty.exploreImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    viewsProperty.exploreNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    viewsProperty.exploreNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewsProperty.cardView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    viewsProperty.exploreNameLabel.textAlignment = .center


//        viewsProperty.exploreNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabelView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
//        viewsProperty.exploreNameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabelView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in the collection view didSelect try calling the class type

```
   let cell = collectionView.cell(indexPath.row) as? ExploreCellData
    if let data = cell.exploreCatagory.......
```

also, try setting the cells       isSelectable
Here’s a website that will help if these don’t work: https://material.io/develop/ios/components/cards/api-docs/Classes/MDCCardCollectionCell.html#/c:objc(cs)MDCCardCollectionCell(py)selectable